# how to listen the stickyheader event in compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm developing android with jetpack compose.
When I add a stickyheader in lazy column, it's working well.
But When I adapt some listener for stickyheader, I can't find any information about this.
Is there any way to catch the stickyheader event?
I want to know that the stickyheader is sticked or not for changing some state by this.